# PDFbox library page iteration

Tags: java, pdfbox

I implemented a method that captures particular area from every single PDF page in a PDF Document, so the method that captures that area takes PDPage and Rectangle objects, now i want to  iterate through every single page and locate first String(text) that located at the coordinates given. getPages() returns PDPageTree so I am a bit stuck since I cant figure out how to check every page , because now it iterates through every page.

```
public PDPageTree getPages() {
    return getPDDocument().getPages();
}

public String firstInvoiceNumber() throws IOException {
    Rectangle invoiceRectangle = new Rectangle(176, 176, 100, 18);
    String headerTextResult = "";
    for (PDPage pd : getPages()) {
        headerTextResult = StripByArea(pd, invoiceRectangle);
    }
    return headerTextResult;
}
```

Comment: If you have already figured out how to iterate through the pages, what is the exact problem you are talking about?

Comment: @second at the moment it iterates through every single page but i am stuck on how to check pages and break once the value is located  > so currently  it goes until the last page and then returns " " because last page does not have the object that I am look for

Comment: Assuming that once your `StripByArea` method (consider using lower case here) returns something that is not `""` you should be able to return. Just check it and either return directly or `break` the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
public String firstInvoiceNumber() throws IOException {
    Rectangle invoiceRectangle = new Rectangle(176, 176, 100, 18);
    String headerTextResult = "";
    for (PDPage pd : getPages()) {
        headerTextResult = StripByArea(pd, invoiceRectangle);
        if(!"".equals(headerTextResult)) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return headerTextResult;
}
```

Comment: Thank you , I dont know what happen to me that i simply could not think of that right away , my Test is now going through successfully